A new Economics.SE is in beta
A new Economics.SE is now in beta, with the hope that it will enjoy a happier ending than the last Economics.SE beta.  
I advertise it here because I believe that CogSci.SE users might have an interest in some of the question on the Economics.SE beta (as evidenced by CogSci.SE efforts to migrate some questions from the former dying beta). In particular you might find an interest in question gathered under the decision-theory tag.
Also, feel free to migrate questions to Economics.SE if it seems relevant.
Hoping both sites can benefit from one another and swiftly move toward graduation.

What happened to the last Econ beta?

I don't know the whole story (I did not participate in the old beta) but it seems that it was terminated after 206 days in beta : area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics. From what I know, it "only" attracted 400 questions in 206 days. The current beta generated more than 150 questions in 15 days, so there is good hopes :) (of course the number of questions per day is just one element to move toward graduation...)
